# How to find and edit duplicates on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form where users are asked to submit a unique ID and their responses populate on a spreadsheet. I want to design a script that finds duplicate IDs and edits the *first instance* of that ID to some string of text like "DUPLICATE."

I know of many scripts that can highlight or delete duplicates, but none that I have found that can edit them.

Thank you!

Comment: A loop `for` with `break` statement inside is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may be a little slow, but I think you'll want something along these lines :

```
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for (var i = lastrow-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var currentID = values[i][3]; //if your ID is stored in the 4th column for example
  for (var j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (values[j][3] == currentID && values[j][3] != "DUPLICATE"){
      sheet.getRange("D"+(j+1)).setValue("DUPLICATE");
    }
  }
}
```

Basically for each line, you take the ID and verify all previous lines to check if any has the same, and replace its value with "DUPLICATE".
It's not a very smart way to do it, but it should work.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thank you!